# Chrome throws Uncaught Error: NOT_FOUND_ERR: DOM Exception 8 error when attempting to refresh Knockout View Model

Tags: knockout.js

I am performing an jquery ajax call that returns a cart and

```
function LoadCart(callback) {
  $.ajax({
    .....removed....

    success: function(cart) {
       callback(cart);
    }
  })
}
```

I have a function which sets up the view model and has Knockout apply bindings..

```
function SetupViewModel(cart) {
  cartViewModel = new CartViewModel(cart);
  ko.applyBindings(cartViewModel);
}
```

This works perfectly fine when the page loads.

But when they delete an item from their cart..

```
var CartViewModel = function(data) {

  .....removed....
  self.deleteCartLine = function(cart) {
    $.ajax({
      ...removed
      success: function(response) {
         $.jGrowl(response.Message, jGrowlOptions)
         loadCart(SetupViewModel);
      }   
    }
  }
}
```

I attempt to Load the cart and setup the CartViewModel again.  This is when I get the 
**NOT_FOUND_ERR DOM Exception 8** error.

Is this because I am attempting to perform a refresh from within the viewModel itself (i.e the LoadCart needs to be called after existing the CartViewModel?

**NOTE** I am aware that Knockout affords the dynamic update that one would wonder why you need to retrieve the cart again.  But there are server side calculations that I don't want to perform in both places (view model, and server side) - so it would be easier to just grab the cart again and update the view model.

Comment: I think I have seen this error when trying to use a `text` binding on an input element, which is invalid. Inputs require `value` bindings. You didn't post your HTML though, so I can't be sure. Also, `ko.applyBindings` only needs to be called ONCE EVER. After it is called, updating the viewmodel will update the bindings. Calling it in a function is BAD.

Comment: Actually - ko provides a .cleanNode, so you can reapply your view model.  So I am not sure "once ever" is actual true.  Secondly, utilizing requireJS is calling it within a function.

Comment: If you clean it, then you aren't applying twice; at least, not in the sense that multiple applications will try to stack... having trouble phrasing that. Anyway; its still unnecessary. If the viewmodel is applied, then updating the values in the viewmodel is all you need to do. You don't need to clean and reapply it.

Comment: I agree with @Tyrsius, unless you are applying bindings to specific container elements, you should really only need to applyBindings once.  `ko.cleanNode` can help, but it does not get rid of event handlers.  Templating/control-flow is usually a better solution.

Comment: Had the same issue. Just decided to logically prevent dual ko.ApplyBinding. But there is no reason why it should be throwing this error in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

For the DOM error issue, I suspect you've incorrectly setup a binding in your HTML, or you're running into conflicts due to replacing the view model.

Don't replace your view model. Just update it. Knockout is really designed to work with updating your data, rather than replacing it.